# i would like to know how to reverse engineer a steam pc game thats limited to a 30min demo ill explain

Tags: exploit, game-hacking, firmware-analysis, cheat-engine, api-reversing

I Have a steam game its a demo not very big company or anything you are limited to only 30 min of game play then at the end of the 30 min your session ends and you are brought to a screen encouraging you to add to your wish list for when it becomes available and exits you to your desktop where you have to load the game up again and start the 30 min timer you can play as many times as your heart desires just completely exit the application and start it from scratch its very time consuming but not that its hard or super slow I have 1000gs and 16 gbs of American pro ram lol it's just getting old open and closing and you can't buy the game yet I don't or maybe it been abandoned idk it's not a popular name brand its  survival like lumberjacks dynasty type shit slavarion trucker level but if I could use cheat engine to find the said timer value and get the address and change the value saving the address and or who responds to it or answers blah blah I can just need to know the gritty details on certain stuff like the byte no# or double 4byte or float number if the need rounded or not simple value or can I modifier a file or a script in the games files and change it that way cause seems like it be much easier